# how to change the button identifier when click it in xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm new to Xcode and I'm using Swift to program a stopwatch. 
I have three functionalities - Play, Stop & Pause. Play and Pause should be the same button and alternate between states. How do I accomplish this in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user the property selected of button
like this :

setup your button states in `viewDidLoad`:

```
startButton.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Selected)
startButton.setTitle("start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Now you can change the button states when it's tapped:

```
@IBAction func startPauseAction(sender: UIButton) {
   sender.selected = !sender.selected // action changed the selected 
   if sender.selected {
     play()
   } else {
     pause()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an enum for button state

```
enum ButtonType {
    case Stop
    case Play
    case Pause
}
var btnType: ButtonType = .Stop

@IBOutlet weak var actionBtn: UIButton!
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton)  {
switch (self.btnType) {
    case .Stop:
        self.btnType = .Play
        // TODO: Change button image/title for current state
        break
    case .Play:
        self.btnType = .Pause
        // TODO:
        break

    case .Pause:
        // TODO:
        break
    }
}
```